# jQuery Adding Fade In/Out

Tags: jquery, html

I have a small gallery of thumbs that when one is clicked it swaps out the main image contained in the div #main_img. The code below is working.

```
$("#thumbs a").click(function(){
    $("#main_image").html($("<img>").attr("src",this.href));
    return false;
});

    <div id="main_image" class="main_image_style"><img  id="main_pic" src="images/prod_smallpearl.jpg" alt""  /></div>

    <div id="thumbs"><a href="images/prod_smallpearl.jpg"><img src="images/icon_smallpearl.png" alt=" " /></a></div>
```

I want to add a fade in/out. I've tried all sorts of different things but I'm new to jQuery and I'm spinning my wheels. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us the best of the "all sorts of different things".

Comment: That would be like 2 or 3 lines more to code, so one of the different things you've tried is probably very close to the solution... and actually if you code it exactly as you describe it, it should work...

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a callback on the `fadeOut()` to get the proper sequencing:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zfm9c/

```
$('#thumbs a').click(function () {
    var mySrc = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#main_image > img').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).attr('src', mySrc).fadeIn();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Working. Many Thanks!